# Facebook social login get user name, email, phone

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I would like to know what are the prerequirements for facebook API to allow a PHP web page to pull the following user data:

- name
- email
- phone

As far as I understand, pulling the phone number requires that your website is whitelisted with facebook / Websense ?

Please advice.

Thank you!

Comment: http://www.wescutshall.com/2011/12/getting-facebook-user-data-with-php/       Check this article. It's really helpful

Comment: The article uses an old version of the PHP SDK, and therefore is not really useful. It's from 2011!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Facebook uses OAuth, you have to build a so-called login flow. See the docs at

- [Facebook Login for the Web with the JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0)
- [Manually Build a Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0)

Within this flow, you have to [request permissions from the user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0). For your use case, you'll need

- `public_profile`
- `email`

There's no chance to get the phone number out of the Graph API.

Comment: Any other suggestions on how to get the phone number during the social login process ?

Comment: There's **NO** chance to the the phone number via the Graph API. There's no field for it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/#fields